# SpeechRecognizer - The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c#, exception, speech-recognition

I'm trying to make a simple speech controlled app, that is activated like cortana. When I speak something specific like "banana" I want the app to listen for commands. Here is my code:

```
        public async Task SetupRecognizer()
        {
            var WebGrammar = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.WebSearch, "webSearch");
            Recognizer.Timeouts.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6.0);
            Recognizer.Timeouts.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.0);
            Recognizer.Timeouts.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.2);

            Recognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;

            await Recognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
        }

        public async Task Listen()
        {
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Now Listening", "Listening");
            await md.ShowAsync();

            await SetupRecognizer();

            SpeechRecognitionResult Result = await Recognizer.RecognizeAsync();

            await ExecuteCommand(Result.Text);

            if (ShouldShowSpeechRecognitionResult)
            {
                MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(Result.Text, "Result");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }

        }

        public async Task ListenFor()
        {
            ThisPage.ListenButton.IsEnabled = false;

            await SetupRecognizer();
            await Recognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync(SpeechContinuousRecognitionMode.Default);
        }

        private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Result.Text.Contains("banana"))
            {
                await Recognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.CancelAsync();
                await Listen();
            }
        }
```

(The `ListenFor()` task is called by a button click event.)

When I run the app and say "banana" it does call the `Recognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.CancelAsync()` function, but when it gets to 'Listen()' Visual Studio throws an exception:

```
'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'
```

Comment: The ResultGenerated event is probably fired on a worker thread.  Use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window to verify.

Comment: [This is my threads window](http://prntscr.com/hmkla9)

Comment: The yellow arrow points at "Worker thread".  Score another one for psychic debugging.

Comment: Sooo... what do I do?

Comment: You have to invoke back to the UI thread of course.  You did not leave any bread crumbs to guess what framework you use.  Probably ought to contain the "Dispatcher" word.

Comment: You're right. I used  `await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    () =>
                    {
                        Listen();
                    }
                    );` . Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually can you help me with one more thing? When I trigger the `ContinuousRecognitionSession.CancelAsync()` function from the `ResultGenerated()` event more than one time, VS throws a `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The text associated with this error code could not be found.`